# IntelliJ debugger doesn't recognize Java version upgrade

Tags: intellij-idea, java-8

I upgraded to `Java 8` from Java 6.

As per [these instructions](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23455956-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under), in `/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 13 CE.app/Contents/Info.plist` I changed

```
<key>JVMVersion</key>
<string>1.6*</string>
```

to

```
<key>JVMVersion</key>
<string>1.8*</string>
```

My environment variable JAVA_HOME is set to:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home
```

However, when I run the debugger in IntelliJ, it still wants to use Java 6:

```
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java ...
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:60490', transport: 'socket'
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/my/MainClass : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
```

What other settings do I need to change in order for IntelliJ to use the Java 8 JRE?

Answer (score 2):

You changed the IDE's setting. Project setting can be changed here: `File->ProjectStructure->Project SDK`